# how to join datasuorce results from linked servers into SSRS drill-through report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need some advice and direction on this following requirement: I currently have a SSRS report with one dataset and one datasource executing a stored proc 
that passes parameters to other drill-trhough reports; however, next month, the database where the datasource points to will be split into two linked servers.

Servers will contain the same databases, tables, etc. only the data will be split.

How can I combine those datasourses into one and use that as for a drill-through report?

I will have 3 servers configured like this:

- server 1 is the current server where the datasource points to with all the employee data but starting next week sales employee data will no longer be loaded into this server/db.
- server 2 will be the new server containing the only the new sales employee data.The old sales employee data remains in the old server but still needs to be included in the reports.
- server 3 will have a link server to both server 1 and server 2.

All SQL servers are on version 2016 as well as Report builder for 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a lot of SSRS reports that get data from SEVERAL servers. Better yet, it gets data from SQL Server 2016 and DB2 (AS400) servers.

How it is done in my company is, one stored procedure in SQL Server. This stored procedure combines all necessary data from all the servers in question. From here, I've seen the reports built two ways:

1. Upload all this data to a new table in the server and use this table and this server as the data source on SSRS.
2. Never mind about creating a new table. Some people are icky about just throwing a bunch of tables on the server. Not us though, we have thousands of databases and tables because it is easier to manipulate. If you don't want to create a new table, you can just select it in the stored procedure and that will work just fine. Make the data source point to the server where the stored procedure is and make the query call this stored procedure. It will return any data this stored procedure has.

We also have a job that runs this stored procedure everyday on SQL server. That way, our end table is up-to-date and in sync with data from other servers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create linked servers from your current main server to the new ones. That way you can you can access the data directly from the same server by qualifying the table name with

```
[Servername].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[Table]
```

as in the following image.

[image]

How you link to your servers will depend on your particular setup but there is lots of info on how to do this, it's pretty straight forward.